# Check for differentiability.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Define $f$ on $[0,1]$ by setting $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational and $\frac 1q$ if $x=\frac pq$ is rational with $p,q$ in lowest terms. Determine if $f$ is differentiable.

My attempt: this function is not continuous over the rational numbers. hence it is not differentiable over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For $x_0\notin \mathbb{Q}$ we have:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x-x_0}$$

I am not sure how to proceed.

Edit :
I need to check if the limit converges: Let L be a number in $\mathbb R$,
I will only check differentiabilty at irrational points $\implies f(x_0)=0$
$$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-L|=|\dfrac{f(x)-L(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}|
$$
For the above to be less than $\epsilon$, I need to choose an appropriate $\delta$.

For any $\delta$ the interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ will contain rational and irrational points.

hence, $\exists x'\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ such that $x'\notin \mathbb Q$. In this case:
$$|\dfrac{f(x)}{x-x_0}|=|L| $$

Also, $\exists x'\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ such that $x'\in \mathbb Q$. In this case:

$$|\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-L|=|\dfrac{f(x)}{x-x_0}-L|= |\dfrac{\frac{1}{q}}{\frac{p}{q}-x_0}-L|$$

Am I correct so far?

Comment: Hint: Given any real number $L$, you can prove by the epsilon-delta definition of a limit that your limit, if it exists, is larger than $L$.

Comment: I modified my solution is that correct? @aschepler

Comment: You say "not continuous over the rational numbers". In fact, restricted to only the rationals, it is the identity function, which is continuous and differentiable. It is only when you consider the function defined on the reals that problems arise.

Comment: @ ziggurism I want to find the derivative of any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. When $x\in Q$ the function is not continuous and hence not differentiable at any rational point. When $x\notin Q$ I need to evaluate the limit

Comment: Oops, I think my claim was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Irrationals are dense in reals so every rational can be approximated by a sequence of irrational numbers. But the limit does not match as $0 \neq 1/q$. So the function is not continuous at rationals. f is certainly not differentiable at rationals. 
I think the function is continuous at irrationals because to reach an irrational the denominator must get bigger and bigger so $1/q$ tends to $0$.It is not differentiable there (easy to see).